# Atom software after installing not creating shortcut

Tags: atom-editor

After downloading the setup of atom ide I tried to install and turn the antivirus off and it did get install but, it's not creating shortcut so that I can close and open the software again..after closing the software if I try to open it, it again asks to install the software..please help

Comment: which OS u r using??

Comment: Hard to help you here, you have to give some context. _Ideally_, you should describe you're problem detailed enough so we could reproduce the issue. Try to answer the following questions in your question: Which OS are you using? The link for the download page you're getting Atom from? What does the antivirus has to do whit that: expand the setup process. Is there any error message, share with us.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Reproduce

0.Download and install Atom

1.Acknowledge and close the welcome window

2.Go to the start menu and wonder why Atom is not there

3.Go to C:\users\me\ .atom\ and wonder why atom.exe is not there

4.Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\ and wonder why atom.exe is not there

5.Go to Control Panel >> uninstall a program, and wonder why atom.exe is there

6.Restart computer

**Repeat steps 2 through 6**

for better reference, you can follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4liFqsK9nM

**Another solution if you have installed atom in your system already:**

To make Atom recognized as a program in the command line you can try this:

- Open `cmd.exe`
- Navigate to the Atom install folder using `cd %LOCALAPPLDATA%\atom`
- Run `atom --squirrel-updated`

Comment: so accept this as an answer and upvote please to support me